# Rock papers scissors game picture boxes don't change

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I'm making a rock paper scissors game and I have picture boxes to represent what the player and the computer pick.  So in total i have 6 picture boxes.   I have 3 buttons that the person must click to pick rock, paper, or scissors. 
  this is the code for one button that has to do with the picture boxes.  Everything seems right but when ever i press the button to pick either rock, paper, or scissors the picture changes to rock and doesn't change to anything else.  I have 3 buttons that the person must click to pick rock, paper, or scissors.

```
If Label2.Text = "You Won with scissors.  I will get my revenge!" Then paper1.Visible = True

If Label2.Text = "Ha! I win this time, your paper has been cut!" Then Skissors1.Visible = True

If Label2.Text = "oh... A tie, 2 scissors." Then Skissors1.Visible = True

If Label2.Text = "You Won with scissors.  I will get my revenge!" Then Skissors1.Visible = True

If Label2.Text = "Ha! I win this time, your paper has been cut!" Then paper2.Visible = True

If Label2.Text = "oh... A tie, 2 scissors." Then skissors2.Visible = True


    If Rock1.Visible = True Then paper1.Visible = False
    If Rock1.Visible = True Then Skissors1.Visible = False
    If paper1.Visible = True Then Rock1.Visible = False
    If paper1.Visible = True Then Skissors1.Visible = False
    If Skissors1.Visible = True Then paper1.Visible = False
    If Skissors1.Visible = True Then Rock1.Visible = False
    If rock2.Visible = True Then paper2.Visible = False
    If rock2.Visible = True Then skissors2.Visible = False
    If paper2.Visible = True Then rock2.Visible = False
    If paper2.Visible = True Then skissors2.Visible = False
    If skissors2.Visible = True Then paper2.Visible = False
    If skissors2.Visible = True Then rock2.Visible = False
```

Comment: If all 3 are visible, the first 2 if statements will leave rock visible and paper and scissors hidden regardless of what you click. I would use the Click event of each picture to set the other 2 to hidden.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear but i am a bit confused.  How would the first 2 statements make rock visible regardless?  Also if you see the edits i have buttons to click to show the pictures so I don't think I can use the button click event.

Comment: If Rock is visible then you set paper to hidden, and skissors to hidden (Visible=False). Then on the 3rd line, Paper1 will not be true and on the 5th line, skissors1 will not be true because you set them Visible=False on the first 2 lines.